# Cake PHP - howto - Linke database model to non database model

Tags: cakephp

How do i Link a database model to a model without database?

hier some code from the database model:

```
class Vhost extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = 'domain';
    public $hasOne = array('user' => array('className' => 'User'));
     ...
 }
```

And hier the code for the none database model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = false;
}
```

the reason why i try it is because my User Model should get Data from LDAP and my Vhost Model is SQLite driven.

Answer (score 0):

Cake won't support something like that out of the box. The purpose of defining associations such as $hasOne, $belongsTo, $hasMany etc is so that Cake can automatically put together an SQL statement that joins two records and fetches them both in a single query - to a single database.

If you can't compose a single SQL statement yourself that can join the two records together, Cake certainly won't be able to do it automatically.

If you want to do this, you'll need to forget Cake's associations (hasMany, belongsTo, hasOne, etc) and code it manually yourself. I have no experience with LDAP, but I imagine you're going to have to fetch the user from LDAP, and fetch the Vhost, as two separate steps, and then piece the two bits of data together manually.